# Is לְהַעֲמִיד֣וֹ in 2 Chronicles 9:8 singular or plural?

Tags: referent-identification, 2-chronicles

> 2 Chronicles 9:8 "Blessed be the LORD your God who delighted in you, setting you on His throne as king for the LORD your God; because your God loved Israel establishing **them** [לְהַעֲמִיד֣וֹ] forever, therefore He made you king over them, to do justice and righteousness."

to establish them
לְהַעֲמִיד֣וֹ (lə·ha·‘ă·mî·ḏōw)
Preposition-l | Verb - Hifil - Infinitive construct | third person masculine **singular**
Strong's Hebrew 5975: To stand, in various relations

In https://biblehub.com/2_chronicles/9-8.htm, 25 of 27 versions translate לְהַעֲמִיד֣וֹ as plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the translators of most English Bible translations interpret the pronominal suffix וֹ (-o) on לְהַעֲמִידוֹ as referring to the collective nation of Israel represented by a singular pronoun.

But, to whom or what does that pronominal suffix refer? Does it refer to the collective nation of Israel? Or, perhaps it refers to the throne (viz, כִּסְאוֹ) mentioned earlier in the same verse.

There appears to be mention in the Tanakh of Yahveh’s throne (upon which Solomon sits) being “established” forever, but the verses use different verbs than the one in question, including conjugations of the verbs קוּם (*kum*) and כּוּן (*kun*).<sup>1</sup>

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> See the following verses:
2 Sam. 7:16: כִּסְאֲךָ יִהְיֶה **נָכוֹן** עַד עוֹלָם (*kisʾaka yihyeh **nakhon** olam*)—“your throne shall be established forever”
1 Kings 2:45: וְכִסֵּא דָוִד יִהְיֶה **נָכוֹן** לִפְנֵי יְהוָה עַד עוֹלָם (*vekisse David yiyeh **nakhon** lifnei Yahveh ad olam*)—“and the throne of David shall be established before Yahveh forever”
1 Kings 9:5: **וַהֲקִמֹתִי** אֶת כִּסֵּא מַמְלַכְתְּךָ עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל לְעֹלָם (***vahakimoti** et kisse mamlakhteka Yisraʾel leʿolam*)—“and I will establish the throne of your kingdom over Israel forever”
1 Chr. 17:14: וְכִסְאוֹ יִהְיֶה נָכוֹן עַד עוֹלָם (*vekhisʾo yihyeh **nakhon** ad olam*)—“and his throne shall be established forever”
1 Chr. 22:10: **וַהֲכִינוֹתִי** כִּסֵּא מַלְכוּתוֹ עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל עַד עוֹלָם (***vahakhinoti** kisse malkhuto al Yisraʾel ad olam*)—“and I will establish the throne of his kingdom over Israel forever”
Pro. 29:14: כִּסְאוֹ לָעַד **יִכְּוֹן** (*kisʾo laʿad **yikon***)—“I will establish his throne forever”
Isa. 16:5: **וְהוּכַן** בַּחֶסֶד כִּסֵּא (***vehukhan** bachesed kisse*)—“the throne shall be established in mercy”</sup>

Elsewhere, there is certainly precedent for humans being established by Yahveh, using the Hifʿil conjugation of עָמַד (*amad*).<sup>2</sup>

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>2</sup> Exo. 9:16 (Moses); 1 Chr. 17:14 (Solomon)</sup>

To complicate matters, the verbs קוּם (*kum*) and עָמַד (*amad*) appear be synonymous at times,<sup>3</sup> and perhaps even כּוּן (*kun*) and עָמַד (*amad*).<sup>4</sup>

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>3</sup> 1 Kings 15:4; Job 8:5; Nah. 1:6</sup>
        <sup><sup>4</sup> 1 Chr. 17:14</sup>